# Save a webpage completely using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wanted to know how to save a page completely using javascript. i.e When we use chrome-> save as, the html file with its resources is saved right? I wanted to do the same using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no browser API available to JavaScript that does that.